# Django Error: "Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices." Form works for one ID, but not the other

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

Models.py

```
class PointCategoryRecord(models.Model):
    point_category_assignment_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    league_id = models.ForeignKey(League)
    description = models.TextField(default="")
    user_getting_points = models.ForeignKey(TeamMember)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Forms.py

```
class UserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PointCategoryRecord
        fields = '__all__'
```

Views.py

```
def point_form(request, league_id):
    form = UserForm()

    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect(request.path_info)

    form.fields['league_id'].queryset = League.objects.filter(league_id = league_id)
    form.fields['point_category'].queryset = PointCategory.objects.filter(league_id = league_id)
    form.fields['user_getting_points'].queryset = TeamMember.objects.filter(league_id = league_id)
```

urls.py

- I have the path() correct and it's passing the league_id through int:league_id

I'm trying to create a form that filters by the 'league_id' parameter being passed in the views.py function.

I have two objects, one with the league_id of 1 that works perfectly.

The other with the league_id of 2 that throws the "Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices." error.

Any idea why it works for the first ID but not the second?

Comment: In the view code, `form = UserForm()` creates a new empty form, and then you immediately call `form.is_valid()` on the still-empty form, so of course it is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the queryset for the form fields after checking if the form is valid.

```py
def point_form(request, league_id):
    form = UserForm(request.POST or None)  # <-- You should initialize the form with request.POST or None

    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():  # <-- By the time you get here, the form is already invalid
            form.save()
            return redirect(request.path_info)

    # The following lines should be before the form.is_valid() check
    form.fields['league_id'].queryset = League.objects.filter(league_id=league_id)
    form.fields['point_category'].queryset = PointCategory.objects.filter(league_id=league_id)
    form.fields['user_getting_points'].queryset = TeamMember.objects.filter(league_id=league_id)
```

Comment: I've implemented this change, however the error still remains. Even before the change, the form was working, but for only one of the choices. The only "valid" choice is the first id - "1" but not "2" even though it's being recognized as an option.